# LINQ to Lambda Expressions

Tags: linq, lambda

Is there an application or utility that will convert LINQ to Lambda Expressions? (or an add-on to LINQPad)

Comment: Doing this is instructional for learning the the fluent API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LINQPad, you can click on the "lambda" button to get the lamdba version.

Edit:
As RBarry says, its the upside down "y", between "Results" and "SQL".  This shows up in the results page after you execute a query.

Comment: Lambda looks like an upside-down "y".

Comment: That's what I thought. I just tried it again and it's now working. Maybe there was an open thread in the app? Who knows. Time to format c: Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The other day, I was surprised to find that [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does this, at least for C# (not sure about VB, if that's what you need).

Comment: R# is a great tool every developer must have but it's not free.

Comment: Great suggestion, but *where* within ReSharper can I do this? I had a LINQ query and did not know where in the context menu, shortcut key, or which part of the LINQ query to select to convert it to a Lambda.